# AngularJs(ng-repeat) and database good practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, laravel-5

**Context:** 
I'm new in this world of AngularJS and i'm using ng-repeat to show elements that I get from my database with `Laravel`. I need to ask to the database every time that I set the state(active(1) or desactived(0)) to show in two  different tables(active or desactived). I'm using the filter that provides angular.

I need to ask every time because differents session going to see/change the states, but just one can take the object or objects.

I have like 100 elements in this moment, but I'll have more with the time.

**Questions:**
Ask the database, load the data and show whit ng-repeat is too mush costly in the client side?
which is the best way to do this?

Sorry about my english and i hope you understand and can help me.

Google translate is my copilot.

Comment: You say that you query database when filter changes and then, that you use angular's filter mechanism. So where does your filtering actually happens? In the database or on the client side? If you expect more elements then you should definitely filter in database (and consider paging your results)

Comment: query the database every time y change the state from a element to reload de data that i showing in two tables(active and inactive elements) on the client side, the filter is with angular. i need to use just one table, because the B.I software(requirement). I use the same $scope var to this two tables, one filter 0 and the other one filter with 1.

Comment: Hitting database every time your filter changes is not a problem - this is how most of the web applications behave. Refreshing ng-repeat with reasonable number of elements also shouldn't affect your performance. Like I said, your only concern should be to page your results and filter by state IN THE DATABASE. Otherwise, you'll quickly face performance problems and they won't be related to the number of http requests.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. i was concern about the performance on the client side. I understand the filter on the database, but always need all the data, then will be better if I do querys with filters like you said and just repeat on the views.
Thanks a lot this realy help me.